# App in background killed after 5 minutes in Android 9

Tags: android, background, kill, screensharing

I have recently added to my app a feature enabling sharing screen over the network. This feature becomes especially meaningful when I want to stream the mobile screen outside my app, i.e. putting my app in background.
While I have no problem on a Samsung S7 with Android 8, the app is constantly killed on a Samsung Active Pro after being 5 minutes in background. However, *if the tablet is connected to the usb cable (either to a charger or to my PC) the app remains alive*.

I have disabled battery optimizations for my app and tried other possible user-side actions found on the web without success.

Is there anything I can do developer-side?
I've tried to use wakelocks, but that didn't help. In other threads I have read that sending notifications with a foreground service might help: is this a viable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have an [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services), otherwise the OS will kill you app

Comment: Does my service need to accomplish particular tasks or could it be just a dummy?

Comment: once you have an ongoing notification (connected to service), your entire process is alive (so you don't need to do anything inside your service just keep it running)

Answer (score 0):

Android imposed restrictions on background service.Android allows background service only in following scenarios.

An app is placed on the allowlist when it handles a task that's visible to the user, such as:

**1)Handling a high-priority Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) message.**

**2)Receiving a broadcast, such as an SMS/MMS message.**

**3)Executing a PendingIntent from a notification.**

**4)Starting a VpnService before the VPN app promotes itself to the foreground.**

***So,as a work around use Alarm Manager and set an alarm after 10ms to start a service.So,In this case Android is not going to restrict it.***